# Recheck executable hash modification at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, cryptographic-hash-function

For example, if I wrote an hello world program for example in C#,
is there a way to check the running binary for modification at runtime?

We could read the `.exe` file (for example in Linux the `/proc/PID/exe` file), hash it, and compare the hash at runtime, that might works fine, but can we read the (self) running executable as bytes from memory and hash it to check if it's modified by something else at runtime?

Comment: But if it's been modified, then the hash compare can just be removed..

Comment: yeah, it can, I just want to make it harder for people to do so